# Cómo hacer una consulta MYSQL dado un POINT(lat long) para saber cuantos elementos hay disponibles a X kms a la rodonda?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Vale, estoy haciendo un trabajo dónde tenemos que utilizar geolocalización en MYSQL, todo iba bien hasta que tuve que hacer una consulta, he buscado múltiples ejemplos de consultas de ese tipo pero todos tienen en sus tablas columnas que se llaman 'latitud' y 'longitud' y a mi me pedían que guardase como POINT(latitud longitud),
entonces a la hora de hacer la consulta no podía utilizar esos ejemplos.
Por cierto estoy en MYSQL 5.7 y esta es la estructura de mi tabla donde tengo que hacer la consulta:
[image: estructura tabla restaurants]

Y este es un ejemplo de las consultas que he encontrado:

[image: consultas de ejemplo]
Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Comment: Hola drizzy, te damos la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. No te olvides de completar el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y así ganarás tu primera medalla. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo dos sugerencias:

1. Intenta realizar la consulta, creando el punto al especificar la latitud y la longitud
   Por ejemplo:

   `SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE restaurants.coord = point(lat, lng)`

`lat` y `lng` son tus valores numéricos. Desde luego si se trata de un area a la redonda entonces deberas cambiar por coordenadas circulares (o simplemente intervalos rectangulares si quieres hacer pruebas rápidas)

2. Podrias usar los ejemplos que encontras tomando las componentes directamente de tu campo `coord` usando las funciones `ST_Latitude` y `ST_Longitude`

```
SELECT restaurant_id, nom, (6371 * 
ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(ST_Latitude(coord)) * 
SIN(RADIANS(41.9855)) + 
COS(RADIANS(ST_Longitude(coord) - 2.82)) *
COS(RADIANS(ST_Latitude(coord))) *
COS(RADIANS(41.9855))
) AS distance
FROM
restaurants
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

Considerá que he adoptado tu código de los ejemplos, no he probado si funciona, mi principal intensión es que veas como se usan las funciones descritas. Podes encontrar mas información de ellas aquí: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-point-property-functions.html

Espero haber sido útil.
Feliz SQL!

Comment: He hecho la primera consulta y me devuelve un restaurante pero a la hora de hacer la segunda consulta me sale error y que las funciones de ST_Longitude y ST_Latitude no existen

Comment: Por si no leíste en el enlace que te pasé, ST_Latitude y la otra refieren a puntos con "geographic spatial reference system (SRS)". Rápidamente podrías probar ST_X y ST_Y

Comment: Respecto a la primera consulta, te dije que ese tomaría un punto específico en un sistema coordenado, para tomar áreas deberás definir una circunferencia o un rectángulo que contenga el punto